# In nodejs, how can I capture logging output of Flask launched by PythonShell?

Tags: node.js, flask

I have implemented a flask endpoint which writes a string to the log:

```
@app.route("/") 
@cross_origin()
def hi():
    print("hi")
    app.logger.info("hi2")
    return "hi"
```

If I invoke flask from the command line, then hit that endpoint from the browser, flask logs the string as I expect:

```
$ FLASK_ENV=development python py/server.py
 * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 223-046-607
hi
[2020-08-07 12:03:54,269] INFO in server: hi2
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 12:03:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here is my naïve attempt to capture flask output from a renderer by calling the `on()` method of a `PythonShell` instance:

```
function sendToPython_dev() {
    let { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');
    let options = {
        mode: 'text'
    };
    let pythonShell = PythonShell.run('./py/server.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('response: ', results);
    });
    // Attempt to capture flask logging output
    pythonShell.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log('flask', message);
    });
}
```

I invoke it from the command line like so.  To my surprise, I get the first three lines of logging info that Flask generates at startup - but not the rest of the initialization, nor do I see the logging output when I visit the endpoint in the browser:

```
$ FLASK_ENV=development ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1 npm start

> my-app@1.0.0 start /home/projects/my-app
> electron-forge start

✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Launching Application

[14900:0807/120749.869098:VERBOSE1:CONSOLE(31)] "Main._createAppUI: 26.96875ms", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/main/main.js (31)
[14900:0807/120749.885893:VERBOSE1:CONSOLE(31)] "Main._showAppUI: 16.19482421875ms", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/main/main.js (31)
[14900:0807/120749.902785:INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "flask  * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)", source: file:///home/projects/my-app/src/renderer.js (16)
[14900:0807/120749.905309:INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "flask  * Environment: development", source: file:///home/projects/my-app/src/renderer.js (16)
[14900:0807/120749.905424:INFO:CONSOLE(16)] "flask  * Debug mode: on", source: file:///home/projects/my-app/src/renderer.js (16)
[14900:0807/120749.920625:VERBOSE1:CONSOLE(31)] "Main._initializeTarget: 10.156005859375ms", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/main/main.js (31)
[14900:0807/120750.021953:VERBOSE1:CONSOLE(31)] "Main._lateInitialization: 0.653076171875ms", source: devtools://devtools/bundled/main/main.js (31)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that print statements were showing up, but not log messages.  I suppose that those first few messages from Flask initialization are print statements rather than log messages.

So I fixed the problem by redirecting the logger to stdout:

```
app = Flask(__name__) 
import sys, logging
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Now Flask log messages appear in Electron's Chromium console.

I cleaned up the syntax of the renderer a little bit.

```
function sendToPython_dev() {
    let { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');
    let options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonOptions: ['-u']
    };
    PythonShell.run('./py/server.py', options, function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('response: ', results);
    }).on('message', function (message) {
        console.log('flask', message);
    }).on('stderror', function (message) {
        console.log('flask error', message);
    });
}
```

Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to accept my own answer.